# Django order_by() returning wrong queryset

Tags: django

I am trying to get a list through a queryset that gives me an ordered list with fields across different models.

I have two models:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    total_score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-total_score']

class Individual(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='individuals')
    score = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-score']
```

This is the queryset I am using:

```
Team.objects.order_by('-total_score', '-individuals__score')
```

From my understanding, this will order by descending total score, followed by descending individual scores. However, whenever I have teams with same total score and individuals in these teams with similar scores, this queryset does not compare each individual score across different teams. How do I fix this? I am trying to rank these teams and break ties based on the scores of individuals. I am using postgresql.

**Edit**

So for example if I have:

Team A:  Player One=**10**, Player Two=**10**, Player Three=**5**, Player Four=**0** (total = **25**)

Team B:  Player One=**10**, Player Two=**10**, Player Three=**3**, Player Four=**2** (total = **25**)

Team B:  Player One=**10**, Player Two=**10**, Player Three=**2**, Player Four=**2** (total = **24**)

I am expecting this query to return Team A, Team B, Team C. But It gives me Team B, Team A, Team C instead.

I have a function that gets rid of the duplicates:

```
teams = Team.objects.order_by('total_score', '-individuals__score')
    for team in teams:
        if squad not in dup_list:
            dup_list.append(team)
            rank_list.append(team)
    teams = rank_list

    return rank_list
```

Comment: Do a print(Team.objects.order_by('-total_score', '-individuals__score').query) and examine the SQL and see where it is going sideways on you.

Comment: It's not clear what you expect ordering the teams by `'-individuals__score'` to do. It will return the same team object multiple times, once for each individual in the queryset. See the [note in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) for more info.

Comment: I added more details @Alasdair can you figure out what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

When you sort on `-individuals__score`, each team appears multiple times, once for each individual.

The teams are then sorted based on *that* individual. You want to sort based on the list of individual scores for that team e.g. comparing `[10,10,5,0]` and `[10,10,3,2]`. You might be able to do this with [expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/expressions/) but I can't help with that.

If you're using Postgres, one option might be to add an `ArrayField` to `Team`, store values like `[10,10,5,0]`, and sort based on that.